# spark submit job with configuration file

Tags: apache-spark

A job will be submitted with spark-submit in yarn-client mode. A properties file , AA.conf, is inside $current_dir.

(1) the AA_With_All_Jars.jar will be copied to all nodes ?
(2) AA.conf will be copied to all nodes ?
(3) if an ouput file is generated to $current_dir/data, it will work ?

If the mode is changed to yarn-cluster, what will happen ? same ?

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$current_dir/AA_With_All_Jars.jar"  \
--class "MyMain" \
--master yarn-client \
--num-executors 4 \
--driver-memory 16g \
--executor-cores 10 \
--executor-memory 6g \
$current_dir/AAA-assembly.jar $current_dir T-2 2>&1 | tee ./my_log
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question

From what i understand you can do the spark submit by specifying the path of the configuration file. The best approach i suggest is to move the jar files and configuration files to the hdfs and then submit.

Answer (score 0):

below is my answer

(1) the AA_With_All_Jars.jar will be copied to all nodes ?

**yes this will be copied to all nodes**

(2) AA.conf will be copied to all nodes ?

**no only jars file be copied**

(3) if an output file is generated to $current_dir/data, it will work ?

**the output of spark job is , you are writing to HDFS so you can access from any node**